# C# REST - Send Request Body, Receive Response Body

Tags: c#, .net, rest, silverlight

I'm using the WebClient class. I've had some luck with the OpenReadTaskAsync method with a GET, but right now, I want to call a POST, or PUT REST method. I figured that I should use UploadStringTaskAsync. But, when I call this method on a working REST service, I get this error:

System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported on this request.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.set_Method(String value)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.UploadStringAsync(Uri address, String method, String data, Object userToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at CF.RESTClientDotNet.Silverlight.Sample.MainPage.d__3.MoveNext()

This is the code

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
var returnValue = await webClient.UploadStringTaskAsync(uri.AbsoluteUri, "POST", bodyString);
```

Comment: Based on the StackTrace I would say the server doesn't want you to POST ... not much you can change client-side to overcome that ...

Comment: Retrieve the http header of the service to know the allowed verbs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up completely redesigning my library. There are samples here:

https://bitbucket.org/MelbourneDeveloper/restclient-.net/src/master/

NuGet: Install-Package RESTClient.NET